# Array extension/reduction

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I work with Oracle JGeometry method which returns (or takes as method argument) 2D segments as double array (x1,y1,x2,y2 ... xn,yn). I would like to extend this array to contain 3D segments as double array (x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2 ... xn,yn,zn) by default Z value or reduce to 2D (by removing of all Z coordinate). I wrote simple utility methods for making this. Is there any easier or smarter way to do this?

The conversion from 2D to 3D:

```
public static double[] to3D(double z, double[] inputArray) {
    List<Double> convertedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        convertedItems.add(inputArray[i]);
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0) {
            convertedItems.add(z);
        }
    }
    return convertedItems.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
}
```

The conversion from 3D to 2D:

```
public static double[] to2D(double[] inputArray) {
    List<Double> convertedItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
       if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0) {
           continue;
       }
       convertedItems.add(inputArray[i]);     
    }
    return convertedItems.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
}
```

Comment: If your code is working as expected and all you want is advice on improvements then perhaps it is better to ask at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: You can check a recommended approach here - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256865/184584

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should offer some performance improvements.

```
public static double[] to3D(double z, double[] inputArray) {
    if (inputArray.length % 2 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    double[] convertedArray = new double[inputArray.length / 2 * 3];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length / 2; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(inputArray, i * 2, convertedArray, i * 3, 2);
        convertedArray[i * 3 + 2] = z;
    }
    return convertedArray;
}

public static double[] to2D(double[] inputArray) {
    if (inputArray.length % 3 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    double[] convertedArray = new double[inputArray.length / 3 * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length / 3; i++) {
        System.arraycopy(inputArray, i * 3, convertedArray, i * 2, 2);
    }
    return convertedArray;
}
```

Comment: The performance really better! From 49ms to 4ms for ten elements...